# docker swarm unlock key lost

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have a **swarm** running on **AWS** and I didn't save the **unlock key**,
I restarted my nodes without saving the **key**, then I couldn't unlock my **swarm**.

I want to know if there's a way to retrieve the **swarm unlock key.**

Thanks.

Comment: That would defeat the point of having it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ceejayoz it's a dev environment and the key is lost accidentally.

Comment: None of that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The same could happen if you would [rotate the unlock key](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm_manager_locking/#rotate-the-unlock-key). There's a warning to in the docs to keep the old key for a few minutes in case it goes down before recieving the new key.